# Insert new record when updating information?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am developing online shopping cart system, I have items and item_options tables.

Each Item can have 1 or more options, see below.

**items table**

- item_id (PK)
- item_name
- item_description

Note: item prices are in the item_options tables

**item_options table**

- option_id (PK)
- item_id (FK)
- option_name
- option_price

When the customer placed an order, the data will be added into the order and order_items table.

**orders table**

- orders_id (PK)
- customer_id (FK)
- address_address_id (FK)
- date_purchased
- orders_status
- orders_date_finished

**order_items table**

- orders_items_id (PK)
- orders_id  (FK)
- item_id (FK)
- item_option_id (FK)

There is a problem, if the staffs change the price, item name or delete a item.. the customer invoices will be affected because the FK from the order_items will no longer be existed in the items table. What is the solution to this?

How about this solution: add active field in the `items` and `item_options`  tables. When the staffs want to change the price or name of a item - just turn the current active record to 0 (`items.active`) and then insert a new record with the new information and active become 1. The old orders still point the correct id of the entry that is not active. Is this good way doing it?

When the new information has been inserted in the items table, does that mean I have to update/change the new PK ID in the `item_id.item_options` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In something like this, I am definitely against the use of hard deletes.  Every update or delete should be adding a new row into the item_options table and then marking the previous one as inactive (that way there is no chance that a user can select one of the previous values).

Each new item inserted should consist of two steps:

1. Add the item to the items table
2. Using the item_id from the items table, add the item into the item_options table

Comment: Thank you. In regarding number 2. Even I didnt change the option name or price... I stil need to get the value of option_name and option_price first? and then insert into item_options with the new item_id?

Comment: Yes, I believe you would need to because this is now being linked with a new record (item).  Unless I'm not understanding your question correctly ...

Comment: I'll reparase my question just to make sure :) If I change the values from items.item_name and items.item_description only.. I still need to add new records in the item_options table even I did NOT change the values of item_options.option_price?

Comment: That depends.  Should the names change for the existing sales or should they not?  If they shouldn't, then yes you would need to duplicate that data despite it not changing because the item_id has now changed.  However, if you don't mind the values changing (item_name), then you can just do an update on that without having to reinsert that data.

Comment: Thank you for information, is there any opensource shopping cart that does similar job?

Comment: There are a few open source php scripts for e-commerce apps out there: http://blog.webdistortion.com/2008/05/03/9-kick-ass-open-source-e-commerce-platforms-reviewed/

Answer (score 2):

The typical solution to this that I've seen is to store the snapshot of the data that you want a history of in a separate table.  That way you can store only the data you want a snapshot of at the time of the invoice, instead of all data in a particular table.

It will also help to store history data away from live data when it comes to simplifying reporting and queries in the code.. generally these two things don't need to be accessed at the same time, so you avoid the more complex queries (and heavier load on a single table) just to access one or the other.

Comment: That is not a bad idea. If I understood you correctly, I need to  create new tables: history_items, history_item_options?  To display past orders for the customer firstly check the data from current items table first and if item_id not found then check in history_items.item_id?

Comment: The exact details of the implementation will be up to your business rules, but 1 scenario I've seen only stores history data of things that are likely to change (like price), along with a ref to the item ID.  Specific item defining data (catalog #, etc) is not likely to change or matter when it does (and can in fact be made unchangeable), so you don't have to store it every time.  This also gives you flexibility to apply invoice-specific price adjustments outside of item definitions (system overrides, discount code adjustments, etc) so that the invoice price is not tied to item definition.

Comment: One thing to note in addition to above.. in this scenario you don't delete items that are no longer supported, you just mark them "deleted" or "expired" and keep them in the system so the old invoices can reference them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do things the way you describe, you are going to have to add a new rows to the item_options table to handle the new items.

Comment: Why do I have to add a new rows to the item_options if Im only changing the item.name for example? If I change the price in item_options.option_price - does that mean I have to add new rows in items table? Is this the best soltion?